# How to install and use Facebook PHP SDK without Composer

Tags: php, facebook, events, sdk

I'm trying to embed `Server` Side conversion in a website (due to `iOS` 14 update) but I'm experiencing issues with the `PHP` `SDK` so everytime I try a conversion code in a page it turns out `Fatal Error`.
So my question is, how can I use/embed correctly these conversions code?

Thanks in advance to who will answer

EDIT: To explain better

I Downloaded the Facebook Php SDK from here https://php-download.com/package/facebook/php-sdk-v4 and then I uploaded in my website root, after that I've included the following code(from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/payload-helper ) in a thank you page to track "purchase" conversion:

```
<?php
define('SDK_DIR', __DIR__ . '/..'); // Path to the SDK directory
$loader = include SDK_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Content;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\CustomData;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\DeliveryCategory;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Event;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Gender;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\UserData;

// Configuration.
// Should fill in value before running this script
$access_token = null;
$pixel_id = null;

if (is_null($access_token) || is_null($pixel_id)) {
  throw new Exception(
    'You must set your access token and pixel id before executing'
  );
}

// Initialize
Api::init(null, null, $access_token);
$api = Api::instance();
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$events = array();

$user_data_0 = (new UserData())
  ->setEmail("hashed email");

$custom_data_0 = (new CustomData())
  ->setValue(142.52)
  ->setCurrency("USD");

$event_0 = (new Event())
  ->setEventName("Purchase")
  ->setEventTime(1620379012)
  ->setUserData($user_data_0)
  ->setCustomData($custom_data_0)
  ->setActionSource("email");
array_push($events, $event_0);

$request = (new EventRequest($pixel_id))
  ->setEvents($events);

$request->execute();
```

Of course this code do not contain token and pixel ID but in the website I filled all the variables with the right values.
I also adjusted the require on top with the right path and then i got the following error in the page:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FacebookAds\Api' not found in mywebsite/public_html/template/includes/analyticstracking2.inc.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /mywebsite/public_html/it/thankyou_page.php(134): require() #1 {main} thrown in mywebsite/public_html/template/includes/analyticstracking2.inc.php on line 60

On line 60 there's the following: Api::init(null, null, $access_token);
Onestly I do not understand where the issue it's coming from.

Now to answer to 'why do not use composer' I can't from a shared hosting server, if someone knows howo to do maybe I can start from there.

Comment: Download the code, put it somewhere in your project and include all necessary files manually. That's basically it. Which files you need etc is a bit off-topic here since we're not facebooks support channel. If you have some specific error you get when using your code, then please post the full error message together with all your relevant code. Fatal errors can occur for _many_ different reasons. However, why not just install it using composer? It would save you some major headaches.

Comment: They follow the PSR-4 autoloading standard with the SDK, so you can either use your own implementation for that, https://pretzelhands.com/posts/build-your-own-psr-4-autoloader - or you simply fix one of the fatal errors you get after the other (I am assuming, initially most of them will be about undefined classes), by requiring whatever class file the current error indicates is missing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hi and thanks a lot, I'll edit my question with some code to explain better, by the way the fatal Error was exactly on the require added to the code.
I'll add some code right now

Comment: You don't need to run composer on the server itself to reap the benefits from using it. Just handle all the composer installs/updates locally on your machine and then deploy the vendor folder as a part of your application, just like any custom folder/code you have.